# variable in ajax call holding old data

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, wordpress

I have the following code which I'm trying to use as an ajax load more feature on displaying wordpress / woocommerce posts but the value of 'cat' always seems to stay on the first value it gets.

Do i need to delete it each time or something similar so it starts holding the correct 'cat' ?

```
var ppp = 4; // Post per page
var pageNumber = 1;

$(".et-load-more").on("click", function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var cat = $('.et-load-more').data('category');
  pageNumber++;

  $.ajax({
    cache: false,
    url: nanook_ajax_obj.ajaxurl,
    data: {
      'action':'more_post_ajax',
      'cat' : cat,
      'ppp' : ppp,
      'page' : pageNumber
    },
    success: function(html, data) {
      $(".products").append(html);
    },
    error: function(errorThrown) {
      console.log(errorThrown);
    }
  });
});
});
```

And the function from functions.php

```
function more_post_ajax(){

        $ppp = (isset($_POST['ppp'])) ? $_POST["ppp"] : 4;
        $page = (isset($_POST['page'])) ? $_POST['page'] : 2;
            $cat = (isset($_POST['cat'])) ? $_POST['cat'] : '';

        $args = array(
            'post_type' => 'product',
            'posts_per_page' => $ppp,
            'cat' => $cat,
            'paged'    => $page
        );

        $loop = new WP_Query($args);
            $postcount = $loop->max_num_pages;
        $out = '';
            ?>
            <ul class="products">
            <?php

            echo $postcount;
        if ($loop -> have_posts()) :  while ($loop -> have_posts()) : $loop -> the_post();
            $out .= wc_get_template_part( 'content', 'product' );

        endwhile;
            ?>
        </ul>
        <?php
        endif;
        wp_reset_postdata();
        die();
    }

    add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_more_post_ajax', 'more_post_ajax');
    add_action('wp_ajax_more_post_ajax', 'more_post_ajax');
```

And heres the visual composer element code :

```
// Product Grid
function productgrid_func( $atts ) {

 ob_start();
   extract( shortcode_atts( array(
  'nanook_extra_class' => '',
 ), $atts ) );


?>
 <div id="ajax-posts" class="row">
         <?php
             $postsPerPage = 8;
                         $cat = '';
             $args = array(
                     'post_type' => 'product',
                     'posts_per_page' => $postsPerPage,
                     'product_cat' => $cat
             );

             $loop = new WP_Query($args);
                         $cat_id = $cat;

                         ?>
                         <div class="et-product-cats">

                                <a class="cat-trigger active" href="">
<?php echo 'All'; ?></a>
                            <?php $wcatTerms = 
get_terms('product_cat', array('hide_empty' => 0, 'orderby' => 'ASC',  'parent' =>0));
                                            foreach($wcatTerms as 
$wcatTerm) :
                                            ?>
                                                    <a class="cat-trigger" href="<?php echo get_term_link( $wcatTerm->slug, $wcatTerm->taxonomy ); ?>"><?php echo $wcatTerm->name; ?></a>
                                            <?php endforeach; ?>
                        </div>
                        <div class="et-product-filter-button">
                                <span>Filter</span>
                        </div>
                        <div class="product-grid-cover hidden">
                            <div class="product-grid-preloader">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                         <ul class="products">
                        <?php
             while ($loop->have_posts()) : $loop->the_post();
                ?>
                        <?php $output .= wc_get_template_part( 'content', 'product' );
             endwhile;
                        ?>
                    </ul>
                    <?php

          ?>
     </div>
         <div class="et-load-more" data-category="">
            <span>Load More</span>
        </div>
```

```
add_shortcode( 'productgrid', 'productgrid_func' );
add_action( 'vc_before_init', 'productgrid_integrateWithVC' );
```

Comment: Are you updating the value of `$('.et-load-more').data('category')` anywhere?

Comment: What you are describing as the problem can't be the problem. The selector must be returning a collection of elements where the first element always has the same data value. Adding a .last() to the chain might bandaid the problem, but likely best option would be to properly remove old load more elements.

Comment: Yes the  $('.et-load-more').data('category')  is being updated and shows correct before pushing the load more button so im not sure why its still getting the old data

Comment: is it being updated, or replaced.

Comment: Updated i believe

Comment: Don't pick value from data-* attribute. You can use like this **var cat = $('.et-load-more').attr('data-category');**

Answer (score 0):

You need to get the instance of that class that you are interacting with. Within an event handler `this` will be the element instance from the matching selector

Change

```
var cat = $('.et-load-more').data('category');
```

To

```
var cat = $(this).data('category');
```

What is happening is when you use `$('.et-load-more').data('category');` it looks for all that class in page. But it can only return one value, so it takes it from the first

Comment: Thanks but its still stuck on the first value each time i click it. There is only one of them on the page. i will add the actual function to the post.